Lando Parse Error: Header overflow on Drupal10 site
Im getting the follow error when I start up Lando:
URLS ⚠ APPSERVER URLS ✖ Parse Error: Header overflow ✖ Parse Error: Header overflow ✖ Parse Error: Header overflow ✖ Parse Error: Header overflow
not sure what else to look into, was wondering if anyone else had this same issue.
After this the Drupal 10 site pulls up ok but it's taking forever to load, almost a minute for a page load.

This seems related to this issue.

I had resolved the issue by modifying the php.ini in lando dir and increased the post max and memory limit and restarted lando (rebuild and restart). Thank you for the article.

make sure you do a lando rebuild afterwards
